# Can a class method change a variable in another class as an unforseen side effect?

Tags: python, class, variables, methods

I'm having some problem with two classes. This is what I write in my main loop

```
print(player1.getPosSize())    
ball.setPos(windowWidth, [player1.getPosSize(), player2.getPosSize()],
    [player1.getSpeed(), player2.getSpeed()])    
print(player1.getPosSize())
```

Here are the method definitions if it would help

(Ball class)

```
def setPos(self, windowWidth, playerPosSizes, playerSpeed):       
    playerPosSizes[0].append(playerSpeed[0])
    playerPosSizes[1].append(playerSpeed[1])
    playerPosSizeSp = playerPosSizes
```

(Player Class)

```
def getPosSize(self):
    return self.posSize

def getSpeed(self):
    return self.ysp
```

this is the output:

```
[80, 285.0, 40, 150]    
[80, 285.0, 40, 150, 0.0]
```

So the list that `getPosSize()` returns is changed. This is weird because `getPosSize` returns a list `posSize` that exists ONLY in the class player. And I'm using the VALUE of `posSize` in the method of AN OTHER class. I don't see how `posSize` list can be changed! I mean when I call `getPosSize` I will get a copy of the `posSize`, right? So when I use that copy in the method `setPos` of the ball class the original `posSize` shouldn't change.

I'm really sorry if the code looks confusing I've tried to only include the relevant parts.

Comment: on SO ypu have to add exrta 4 space before evry line of code. it is easier to do it in your editor before you paste to SO.

Comment: python doesn't create copy for lists when you use `=`.  you have two references to the same data in memory. you need `new_list = other_list[:]` or `new_list = other_list.copy()`

Comment: It's not totally clear what your code is doing. It would help if you post a [mcve] that focuses on your problem. However, calling `getPosSize` does **not** create a copy of `self.posSize` (which I assume is a list), it returns a reference to the actual list object. If you want a copy of the list you need to make one, eg `return  self.posSize[:]`

Comment: Ah, ok. Thx. Seems like someone did it for me though ^^

Comment: See the [copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) module in the Python documentation to understand what's happening and how to resolve it in general cases.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna try to use [:] and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Any `mutable` object such as `list` can be changed by anything that has access to it. Ie. if your `getPosSize()` method is returning the`list` itself, you can make changes that will affect the same list.

```
class One(object):
    CLS_LST = [1, 2, 3]
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = [4, 5, 6]

    def get_cls_pos(self):
        return One.CLS_LST

    def get_pos(self):
        return self.lst

class Two:
    def do_smthng(self, data):
        data.append(-1)



a = One()

print('This is One.CLS_LST: {}'.format(a.CLS_LST))
print('This is a.lst: {}'.format(a.lst))
b = Two()
print('Calling b do something with One.CLS_LST')
b.do_smthng(a.get_cls_pos())
print('This is One.CLS_LST: {}'.format(a.CLS_LST))
print('Calling b to do something with a.lst')
b.do_smthng(a.get_pos())
print('This is a.lst: {}'.format(a.lst))
```

The result of this code will print:

```
This is One.CLS_LST: [1, 2, 3]
This is a.lst: [4, 5, 6]
Calling b to do something with One.CLS_LST
This is One.CLS_LST: [1, 2, 3, -1]
Calling b to do something with a.lst
This is a.lst: [4, 5, 6, -1]
```

If you really want to pass the copy of list, try to use `return list[:]`.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know this. Edited it and it seems to work for now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like two variables in your code link to the same list, so changing one of them will change the other.

Didn't you do anything like `ball.posSize = player1.posSize`?

If yes, you created a second reference to the same list.

To fix this, change `ball.posSize = player1.posSize` to `ball.posSize = player1.posSize[:]`